# IntelliJ: Spring annotations are not recognized/Do not trigger auto-import. Manual import works

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-annotations

I created a new Spring project in IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.2 via the Spring Initializr as a Maven Project and when I try to annotate any of my classes with Spring annotations [IntelliJ does not recognize them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Tc0.png) ("Cannot resolve symbol 'Controller'"). [The pom has the relevant dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOgLv.png) and if [I manually import the class the annotation is recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flE4b.png).

I tried finding a solution online but from what I could tell there is noone else with this specific problem.

To fulfill the requirement of this being a question: How do I configure IntelliJ/Maven/Spring or whatever my be responsible for this mishap to appropriately show and import the respective Spring classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following settings: *Preferences | Editor | General | Auto Import | Exclude from import and completion* list. In case import becomes resolved after you type it manually, but not suggested/completed by IntelliJ IDEA, probably you've added some of the Spring libs to the exclusion list.

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you check spring dependencies added in POM.
2. Needs add this anotations @EnableAutoConfiguration, @SpringBootApplication in the main class.
3. check .m2 folder and class path lib wther all jar downloaded or not.
4. Check once Controller.class is available or not, in eclipse we use the command ctrl+t.
5. Try take any spring boot example from github and import into inteliJ

Comment: ad 1.: The dependencies are there, correct and downloaded by maven. The whole application works when I manually import the respective classes.

ad 2.: The main class (generated by the Initializr) already carries the "@SpringBootApplication" annotation. "@EnableAutoConfiguration" is -again- not recognized unless importet manually. https://imgur.com/KTin2AJ

ad 3.: See 1

ad 4.: In IntelliJ it's ctrl + H and if you manually import the class it is very much aware  of the respective class hierachy. https://imgur.com/XyTq7Ka

ad 5.: I guess I could try and see if IJ does something different